# Vertical, Scrollable List of Panels

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using Adobe Flex Builder 4.5, and I'd like to create a vertical, scrollable list of panels for an AIR application. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A little something like this:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="dp">
        <fx:Object title="Panel A" content="content AAAAA" />
        <fx:Object title="Panel B" />
        <fx:Object title="Panel C" />
        <fx:Object title="Panel D" />
    </s:ArrayCollection>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List dataProvider="{dp}" height="100%">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:Panel title="{data.title}">
                    <s:Label text="{data.content}" />
                </s:Panel>
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Doesn't matter whether you're in AIR or just Flex.